# Use CaCO3 powder as antacid agent

Tags: acid-base

A well known strategy for paper maintenance is to store it in a antacid enviroment
(special boxes, envelopes etc.).

There are also special preservation acid-free papers and archival material (envelopes etc.) "buffered" with a base material (usually $\ce{CaCO3})$ to help keep the pH of the paper to be preserved in the $>7$ pH zone for as much as possible.

I was wondering if we could simply use a $\ce{CaCO3}$ powder (talk or chalk powder) to spray the paper to be preserved instead of using a $\ce{CaCO3}$ infused paper?

Comment: Instead of what? You said yourself that we already do that, i.e., use paper with CaCO3. If you are referring to spraying the _old_ documents, then no, we'd rather keep them as they are.

Comment: If the paper is unavailiable wouldn't a CaCO3 powder have the same result? Edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: To an extent, it would, though it probably won't penetrate quite as deep. Then again, what is it that we want to keep? If it is a new document, just use the modern paper (which in these days is nearly always CaCO3 infused). If it is a historical document, the archivists are very reluctant to alter them in any way.

Answer (score 3):

**Preserving paper by deacidification is not a simple process as you have to infiltrate the paper with the antacid component**

The basic strategy of putting some sort of buffer against acids to preserve paper against degradation is sound. But it isn't easy to achieve. Using carbonate powder won't work as the powder won't infiltrate the substance of the paper where the degradation occurs (and chalky books will be messy to handle).

But there has been a lot of work of various processes to overcome this limitation. [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_deacidification) summarises some of the known processes but also their limitations (one example originally promoted by NASA used diethyl zinc to infiltrate paper but it turned out to be a very dangerous process to manage as diethyl zinc is dangerous and spontaneously flammable with water and air). But a variety of other commercial processes exist. Some of them seem to work better than others as all have some side effects on the preserved materials (eg there is no point preserving the paper if the process damages the ink!)

But some processes seem to work well. The one described [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0141391010003708), using aminoalkylakoxysilanes even seems to improve the mechanical strength of the paper with few side effects.

Comment: The vast majority of books aren't historically significant for their book form, but rather for their content. So another approach is to computer scan the books and reduce them to a computer file.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes on calcium carbonate layer but its surface action is just limited to pH control. Also, consider baking soda, which may add more than surface pH control due to its solubility.

Some other ideas to address other concerns as well, which may be present in more tropical locales, including threats from things like fungus, bacteria, worms,.. may I suggest adding a layer of basic copper carbonate ($\ce{Cu2(OH)2CO3}$) which I would create as a nano-suspension. [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_copper_carbonate) on basic copper carbonate, to quote

> It also has been used for many years as an effective algaecide in farm ponds and in aquaculture operations.

And, it can also address acidic pollution as would CaCO3:

> Basic copper carbonate is decomposed by acids...

Only one concern is that upon significant acidic dissolution over time into an aqueous copper salt, a possible pigment development.

Interestingly, [per a source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3067274/), to quote:

> Bacteria, yeasts, and viruses are rapidly killed on metallic copper surfaces, and the term “contact killing” has been coined for this process.

So, one may also consider just adding a layer of copper metal (in the form of a [copper nanoparticle suspension](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/55135146/1-s2.0-S0021979707001750-main.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DEvaluation_on_dispersion_behavior_of_the.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20200304%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200304T151125Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c780e752927e37a6cde6bd49e19c84e5d3e7bae96174f4d39f4a9dfae6ea5fd3) by [fast methods](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0927775710001159), which may be transformed into the basic copper carbonate with time (but still potentially, but now more minor, staining issue). However, copper metal is but one choice along with other metals (and their oxides, like [nano-zinc oxide](https://www.badgerbalm.com/s-33-zinc-oxide-nanoparticles-clear-zinc-sunscreens.aspx)) and even precious metals like nano-silver (see this source, [Silver nanoparticles as an effective disinfectant: A review](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329967197_Silver_nanoparticles_as_an_effective_disinfectant_A_review)) with related properties (and less potential staining).